# Java Key Bindings can not be successfully implemented

Tags: java, binding, key

The following is my project

```
public class KeyStrokeExample {

private JFrame jFrame;
private JPanel jPanel;
private JButton jButton;

private Action action;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyStrokeExample keyStrokeExample=new KeyStrokeExample();
    keyStrokeExample.initLayout();
    keyStrokeExample.test();
}

private void initLayout() {
    jFrame=new JFrame("frame");
    jPanel=new JPanel();
    jButton=new JButton("test");

    jPanel.add(jButton);
    jFrame.add(jPanel);

    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void test() {
    action=new AbstractAction() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };
    int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
    InputMap inputMap = jPanel.getInputMap(condition);
    ActionMap actionMap = jPanel.getActionMap();

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK ),"DELETE");
    actionMap.put( "DELETE", new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("test");

        }
    });
}
}
```

I practice from https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/

I don't know why the program not print "test"

when I remove

```
    action=new AbstractAction() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };
```

it can work print test"

I want to understand what happened

Thanks

Comment: You're using the wrong InputMap

Comment: What's the correct InputMap?
Can you gave me an example?

Comment: There are only 3 that you can possibly use -- try the other two one at a time and see what happens. ;)